# I can use cd command to open folder, but can not see folder both in cmd or explorer

Tags: xcopy

When preparing to reinstall Windows OS, I use xcopy to backup a partition (driver letter D) to folder E:\Backup200407
Command line:

```
xcopy D:\ E:\Backup200407\ /E /C /Y
```

After copy, I can use cd command to open folder E:\Backup200407
But I can't see it with dir command, or open E:\ in explorer

[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6laKU.png)

Comment: I'd leave out the `/c` parameter to see if you have any errors.

Comment: I can access folder by type directly E:\Backup200407 in address bar. All folders are ok. But can not see Backup200407  in E: